# Faster Deploy and Start on Android

Tags: android, performance, testing, deployment

im developping with andengine GLES2 on android, but testing is verry slow, everytime i change something i have to wait 15 secs until i can test it on my SamsungGalaxy... is there a way to redeploy faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's normal. Indeed, I can say that 15 secs is relevant mostly. Nevertheless you may try to close unused applications, gains 1-2 secs.